# NullPointerException from Liferay 6.2 JSON Web Service API

Tags: json, vb.net, liferay

I'm pulling my hair out over this.. We had a service in place when we were on Liferay 6.0 that read new entries from out HR database (new hires, terminations, changes, etc). It would then loop through and call the Liferay API using tunnel-web to call the functions to make changes (add user, update user, etc). When we upgraded to 6.2 it broke my custom service and after some trial and error I was able to get some methods working again using the jsonws api.

I worked out a few of them but I am having major problems with user/update-user. I am using VB.net to build a LiferayUser class, call get-user-by-screen-name, fill in values in new LiferayUser object, update values from HR database, convert object to json, call update-user and post the json object.

Right now all I get returned is {"exception":"java.lang.NullPointerException"}. This is also all that shows up in the server logs. I've tried both POST and GET methods, posting a json object. I even tried posting the form parameters to the /invoke method that is used on the api reference.

Has anyone come across this before and resolved it?

Comment: Do you expect us to invest a few hours to reproduce the same behaviour based on your description or would you consider posting some code and information about the NullpointerException - e.g. relevant parts of the stacktrace?

Comment: As I said, doing a GET via URL also gives the same error, so without even doing any coding the error can be generated by accessing  `http://localhost/api/jsonws/user/update-user.41/user-id/33301/birthday-month/1/birthday-day/1/birthday-year/1980/facebook-id/0/prefix-id/0/suffix-id/0/password-reset/false/male/true`